# Does load average affect performance?

Tags: linux, performance, load, benchmarking

For example, first I run a benchmark program when the load average is `0.00`,

then, I run some cpu-consuming task to generate some load to `10.00`, then kill it.

next, now `cpu usage` is `0` but load average is `10.00`, if I run the benchmark program again, will the load average affect the result?

Comment: http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but that doesn't mean your benchmark will run the same.

The answer to your question is no. The load average is a reported value. It is meant to give you an idea of the state of the system, averaged over several periods of time. Since it is averaged, it takes time for it to go back to 0 after a heavy load was placed on the system.

This is just a report, however. Your system isn't really loaded, and the CPU isn't currently taken. A new benchmark you'll run is unaffected by the system's state 5 minutes ago.

With that said, what is true for CPU may not be true for memory. If your loader uses a lot of memory, the kernel might push less used memory into the swap. It will also reduce the amount of memory it has for file cache. Depending on your benchmark, that might affect the benchmark's performance.

Comment: The OP said they killed the load-generating task *before* starting the benchmark.  Unless the benchmark numbers were already sensitive to having the benchmark's files (and required libraries, etc.) hot in disk cache or not, there shouldn't be an effect.

Comment: Yes. That is what I said.

Comment: I guess I forgot to say that's an undesirable property for most benchmarks.  Either it should get its files cached before the timed part, or it should evict them from the cache before the timed part, to control for first run vs. repeated runs.

Comment: Oh, now I remember what I was thinking: your last paragraph makes it sound like there will be *ongoing* effects on file caching.  Most OSes don't take load history over the past couple minutes into account in their virtual memory heuristics.  I guess this stuff is all worth mentioning, but load average itself has nothing to do with it.  (A high-load-average workload doesn't imply high memory, and low load average doesn't rule out something having evicted most of your memory, although it does rule out thrashing.)